# How to display a complex relationship field for Laravel Backpack?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a relationship
Candidate -> Vacancy -> User

Candidate:

```
class Candidate extends Model
{
    public function vacancy()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Vacancy::class,
            'vacancy_has_candidate',
            'candidate_id',
            'vacancy_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Vacancy:

```
class Vacancy extends Model
{
   public function candidate()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Candidate::class,
            'vacancy_has_candidate',
            'vacancy_id',
            'candidate_id'
        );
    }

    public function manager() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'manager_id');
    }
}
```

User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function vacancy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vacancy::class, 'manager_id');
    }
}
```

I want to display in СRUD candidates the field of the relationship in which I call the manager method with the output of the field from the User model.

for example

```
class CandidateCrudController extends CrudController
{
....
    public function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        $this->crud->addFields([
              [
                   'name' => 'vacancy',
                   'type' => 'relationship',
                   'label' => 'Vacancy',
                   'model' => Vacancy::class, 
                   'entity' => 'manager', <- this method in Vacancy model
                   'attribute' => 'title', <- this column name in User
                   'ajax' => true,
              ]
         ]);
...
```

I get an error
"Looks like field vacancy is not properly defined. The manager() relationship doesn't seem to exist on the App\Models\Candidate model"

I can’t understand why the backpack is looking for a manager method in Candidates, although in the model I indicated a Vacancy in which this relationship method exists. And how to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

KorDEM.

You will not be able to achieve that as per Backpack Documentation:

- `entity` is the method that defines the relationship on the current model, in your case `App\Models\Candidate` is the CrudController model. So entity there should be the `vacancy` relation.

If you are using [Backpack\PRO paid addon](https://backpackforlaravel.com/products/pro-for-unlimited-projects) you should be able to list the vacancies with the desired information by using something like:

```php
$this->crud->addField([
   'name' => 'vacancy',
   'subfields' => [
     ['name' => 'manager']
   ]
]);
```

If you need aditional pivot fields you need to provide `->withPivot` in the relation.

Check [BelongsToMany documentation on Backpack website](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-how-to#belongstomany-n-n-relationship)